# Given a set of points, how to calculate similarity transform(translation,scale,rotation)?

Tags: opencv, math, affinetransform

I am trying to register a face by affine warping and notice that sometimes it is skewed too much. I would like to calculate a transformation matrix that has no shear/skew component but still maintain the least square error condition on registration error. How can I do this? The following is how I am doing the affine transformation.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main(int ac, char* av[])
{ 
    vector<Point2f> src;
    vector<Point2f> dst;
    src.push_back(Point2f(100,100));
    src.push_back(Point2f(150,150));
    src.push_back(Point2f(200,200));

    dst.push_back(Point2f(50,100));
    dst.push_back(Point2f(150,150));
    dst.push_back(Point2f(210,220));

    // we want M,solve for it using the following
    // M * U = X
    // M = X * inv(U)
    Mat U=Mat::ones(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    Mat X=Mat::ones(2,3,CV_32FC1);

    U.at<float>(0,0)=dst[0].x;
    U.at<float>(0,1)=dst[1].x;
    U.at<float>(0,2)=dst[2].x;
    U.at<float>(1,0)=dst[0].y;
    U.at<float>(1,1)=dst[1].y;
    U.at<float>(1,2)=dst[2].y;

    X.at<float>(0,0)=src[0].x;
    X.at<float>(0,1)=src[1].x;
    X.at<float>(0,2)=src[2].x;
    X.at<float>(1,0)=src[0].y;
    X.at<float>(1,1)=src[1].y;
    X.at<float>(1,2)=src[2].y;

    Mat M = X *  U.inv();

    //now we have the transform matrix M, we can apply this to any x,y and get the source corrdinates
    float x=20,y=20;
    Mat DST=Mat::zeros(3,1,CV_32FC1);
    DST.at<float>(0,0)=x;
    DST.at<float>(1,0)=y;
    DST.at<float>(2,0)=1;
    Mat SRC = M*DST;
    float xf =SRC.at<float>(0,0);
    float yf =SRC.at<float>(1,0);

    //interpolation etc

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OpenCV has a function "estimateRigidTransform" which computes similarity transform  or affine homography depending on the parameters you choose. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform

Comment: @Micka,thank you. that's what I am looking for. but for some input I get an empty matrix(`[186.64424, 165.34634; 265.9704, 160.57053; 245.2484, 258.79953]
[57.173885, 44.81694; 134.6741, 43.777409; 96.992157, 127.96729]`). Might you know why? In any case, if you put this as answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Never used that function... maybe matrix is 0 if error would be "too big"? how many degrees of freedom does a similarity transform  gave? Is 4 correspondences already overdetermined?

Comment: iirc, it should be 5 dof or at least less than affine. for affine, 3 pairs is minimum required. So for similarity transform, 3 pairs that I have means at least overdetermined or minimum. if it is over determined, then I should get the least square solution otherwise, the solution should be exact. maybe there is two solutions that's why it returns an empty matrix...anyway, i will have to dig deeper to find out how to do it 'by hand'. this function points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCVs similarity transform is `cv::estimateRigidTransform` which allows you to compute a 4 degree of freedom (similarity transform) or 6 degree of freedom (full affine) transformation, depending on the parameters you choose.

see the link for more details:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform

but I am not sure why it doesn't find a solution for some of your input. Please try to use a vector of points instead of a matrix. I've seen cases (afair it was with findHomography though) where OpenCV misinterpreted 3x2 matrix (3 points with 2 dimensions each) to be 2 points with 3 dimensions each instead or vice-versa.