# Difference between SimilarityTransform (scikit-image) and warpAffine (openCV)?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I am currently studying [insightface](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface) and in particular [this preprocess function](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/blob/3fb3f12c3c516482c6810b06e95dbcc7c0d4c177/src/common/face_preprocess.py#L46-L111).

It uses both scikit-image `SimilarityTransform` function ([documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.SimilarityTransform)) and openCV `warpAffine` function ([documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine))

Is there a fundamental difference between the two or are they simply two different ways of calling the same mathematical transformation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [similarity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#In_Euclidean_space) is a special case of an [affine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), in which the shear is 0. (Only scale, rotation, and translation are allowed.) scikit-image also has an AffineTransform object.

The transform objects in scikit-image can be used both to estimate the transform, as pointed out by Piotr, but also to perform the transform, using [`skimage.transform.warp`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.warp).

Answer (score 2):

@Juan's answer is more accurate to the accepted one. The opencv version of `SimilarityTransform` should be `estimateRigidTransform` with `fullAffine=false`.
You should find the answer here
[Given a set of points, how to calculate similarity transform(translation,scale,rotation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904516/given-a-set-of-points-how-to-calculate-similarity-transformtranslation-scale-r)

Comment: Please write the relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Basically both of them represent [affine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). However `SimilarityTransform` is used to compute this transformation between two sets of points and `warpAffine` is used to transform image using affine transformation. The OpenCV's equivalent to `SimilarityTransform` is `getAffineTransform`. You can find more information regarding these functions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html).

Comment: This is just wrong. As described by @Juan, a similarity transform is a special case of an affine transfrom with fewer degrees of freedom.